# Group together records that share either one of two variables

Tags: stata

I am working with Stata and I have a large data set where I need to group records together if they share one of two variables.

For example, take the following three observations:

```
Observation  | matching var1 | matching var2
1              xxx              aaa
2              xxx              bbb
3              yay              bob
```

If I were to group the records by `var1`, the first two observations will be in the same group and the last observation will be in a separate group. Similarly, if I were to group using `var2`, observations two and three will be in in the same group and observation one will be in a separate group. However, if I were to group the records based on a match on either `var1` or `var2`, all observations will be in the same group.

I would like to create a 'group id' variable that will take the same value across all these records.

Any suggestions on how I should go about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/) for tips on how to improve your (future) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *community-contributed* `group_twoway` (available in SSC) can match two variables:

```
ssc install group_twoway
```

Using an additional example from yours:

```
clear

input str3(var1 var2)
"xxx" "aaa"
"yyy" "bbb"
"mmm" "ccc"
"nnn" "ccc"
"mmm" "ddd"
"ooo" "ff" 
"pp"  "eee"
"qq"  "ff" 
"rr"  "u"  
"xxx" "bbb"
end

group_twoway var1 var2, generate(group_id)

Result                           # of obs.
-----------------------------------------
not matched                             0
matched                                10  
-----------------------------------------

list, sepby(group_id) constant

     +------------------------+
     | var1   var2   group_id |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  xxx    aaa          1 |
  2. |  yyy    bbb          1 |
     |------------------------|
  3. |  mmm    ccc          2 |
  4. |  nnn    ccc          2 |
  5. |  mmm    ddd          2 |
     |------------------------|
  6. |  ooo     ff          3 |
     |------------------------|
  7. |   pp    eee          4 |
     |------------------------|
  8. |   qq     ff          3 |
     |------------------------|
  9. |   rr      u          5 |
     |------------------------|
 10. |  xxx    bbb          1 |
     +------------------------+
```